# How to create a  Store Expression for entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have this.

```
var ViewModel = repGeneric.GetListOf<CompanyContact>(p => p.CompanyID == 1).Select(s => new ContactViewModel()
            {
                ContactType = _db.ContactTypeTexts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == s.Contact.ContactType.ID).Txt
            });
```

I would like to put this piece of code

> _db.ContactTypeTexts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == s.Contact.ContactType.ID).Txt

in a function.

How can I do that.? Any Idea. I Try but that's give me this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String GetTxt()'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Model-Defined Function like it is described in [this blog article](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef4-model-defined-functions-level-1-amp-2/) by Julie Lerman.